# What happens if I: host a NodeJS service with docker on port 8080 and expose to world on 8080?

Tags: cloud, hosting

When I do such as on post title in an EC2 instance, I can access the service typically using the URL `$host:$port`. However, when I do it on a local machine, the access `$host` is not my personal IP. How can I access this server instance then?

Comment: instead of the IP, did you try 'localhost:8080' or 127.0.0.1:8080 instead?

Comment: Yes, I have. The traffic flows, but my question is about the reason it does not expose to the world.

Comment: That is because when you run this locally, your home setup does not assume you want to expose any devices to the outside world because it also includes adding risks such as being hacked. You can set this up, but it's quite the configuration in your home router opening ports. It's far easier to run something that you want to expose to the 'world' in a cloud datacenter or service. If you still want to do this, check google with the search term "run a website from home"

Comment: A friend of mine presented the NAT mapping concept and ngrok. I thank you, sir.